# scan windows 7 hotfix by using wsusscn2.cab in powershell offline ,occer HRESULT:0x800B0109,

Tags: powershell, windows-7, sha1

i hava a win7 sp1 computer can't connect to the internet ,i writer a powershell shell use wsusscn2.cab to scan,the detial code is :

```
$computer = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
$UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session 
$UpdateServiceManager = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.ServiceManager 
$OfflineDataFile = "$(Get-Location)\wsusscn2.cab"
$UpdateService = $UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService("Offline Sync Service", $OfflineDataFile , 1) 
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
```

when run this code ,will occur the error:

```
使用“3”个参数调用“AddScanPackageService”时发生异常:“A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800B0109)。 (异常来自 HRESULT:0x800B0109)”
所在位置 C:\Users\test\Documents\无标题1.ps1:10 字符: 61
+ $UpdateService = $UpdateServiceManager.AddScanPackageService <<<< ("Offline Sync Service", $OfflineDataFile , 1) 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

i search the internet ,said i the sha-2 hotfix need to be installed(KB4490628、KB447419),i installed this ,but don't work.